# Common colorbar over groupplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, graphics, groupplots

I have results that I want to present in a groupplot that share a common result range. Naturally, I don't want to show multiple colorbar next to each picture next to each individual picture but one colorbar

- over or under the groupplot spanning from left to right of the groupplot or
- left or right of the groupplot spanning from top to bottom of the groupplot

I got the groupplot working thanks to [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/194477/pgfplots-label-each-group-plots). I tried several things for the colorbar but I was not successful so far:

### Solution try 1

Based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126177/common-colorbar-for-groupplot). But the height is not correct:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\xmin}{0}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\xmax}{1.64}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\ymin}{0}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\ymax}{1}
\begin{groupplot}[
  group style={
    group name=my plots,
    group size= 2 by 4,
    vertical sep=1.5cm
  },
  width=7cm,
  hide axis,
  enlargelimits=false,
  axis equal image,
]
  \nextgroupplot
\addplot graphics [xmin=\xmin,xmax=\xmax,ymin=\ymin,ymax=\ymax]
          {example-image-a};
  \nextgroupplot[
    point meta min=0.0,
    point meta max=1.0,
    colormap/bluered,                     % Colormap preset
    colorbar sampled,                     % Steps in colorbar
    colorbar right,
    colorbar style={
      separate axis lines,
      samples=256,                        % Number of steps
    },
    every colorbar/.append style={
      height=2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/parent axis height}+
               \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/group/vertical sep}
    }
  ]
\addplot graphics [xmin=\xmin,xmax=\xmax,ymin=\ymin,ymax=\ymax]
          {example-image-a};
  \nextgroupplot
\addplot graphics [xmin=\xmin,xmax=\xmax,ymin=\ymin,ymax=\ymax]
          {example-image-a};
  \nextgroupplot
\addplot graphics [xmin=\xmin,xmax=\xmax,ymin=\ymin,ymax=\ymax]
          {example-image-a};
\end{groupplot}
% Labels
\node[below = 0.5cm of my plots c1r1.south] {(a) Timestep 25};
\node[below = 0.5cm of my plots c2r1.south] {(b) Timestep 35};
\node[below = 0.5cm of my plots c1r2.south] {(c) Timestep 45};
\node[below = 0.5cm of my plots c2r2.south] {(d) Timestep 55};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Giving this result:

[image]

Defining a fixed height does not change anything regarding the result. Interestingly I can change the colorbar height with `point meta max=2` option

### Solution try 2

Based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135480/position-of-colorbar-with-multi-plots-without-using-groupplot) I tried using node relative positioning:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\xmin}{0}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\xmax}{1.64}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\ymin}{0}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\ymax}{1}
\begin{groupplot}[
  group style={
    group name=my plots,
    group size= 2 by 4,
    vertical sep=1.5cm
  },
  width=7cm,
  hide axis,
  enlargelimits=false,
  axis equal image,
]
  \nextgroupplot
    \addplot graphics [xmin=\xmin,xmax=\xmax,ymin=\ymin,ymax=\ymax]
          {example-image-a};
    \coordinate (top) at (rel axis cs:0,1);% coordinate at top of the first plot
  \nextgroupplot
    \addplot graphics [xmin=\xmin,xmax=\xmax,ymin=\ymin,ymax=\ymax]
          {example-image-a};
  \nextgroupplot
    \addplot graphics [xmin=\xmin,xmax=\xmax,ymin=\ymin,ymax=\ymax]
          {example-image-a};
  \nextgroupplot
    \addplot graphics [xmin=\xmin,xmax=\xmax,ymin=\ymin,ymax=\ymax]
          {example-image-a};
    \coordinate (bot) at (rel axis cs:1,0);% coordinate at bottom of the last plot
\end{groupplot}
% Labels
\node[below = 0.5cm of my plots c1r1.south] {(a) Timestep 25};
\node[below = 0.5cm of my plots c2r1.south] {(b) Timestep 35};
\node[below = 0.5cm of my plots c1r2.south] {(c) Timestep 45};
\node[below = 0.5cm of my plots c2r2.south] {(d) Timestep 55};
% Colorbar
\path (top|-current bounding box.north)--
                    coordinate(legendpos)
                    (bot|-current bounding box.north);
\begin{axis}[%
  hide axis,
  scale only axis,
  %height=.6\linewidth,
  %width=.9\linewidth,
  at={(top.north)},
  anchor=north west,
  point meta min=0.0,
  point meta max=2.0,
  colormap/bluered,                     % Colormap preset
  colorbar horizontal,                  % Active colorbar
  colorbar sampled,                     % Steps in colorbar
  colorbar style={
    separate axis lines,
    samples=256,                        % Number of steps
  },
]
  \addplot [draw=none] coordinates {(0,0)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This gives me a colorbar but it is not nearly where I would expect it and the width is not from left to right of two subplots:

[image]

Any ideas how to fix the colorbar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I basically got what I want with the second attempt. But the solution is not as automated as I would like it to have concerning width and position of the colorbar

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\xmin}{0}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\xmax}{1.64}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\ymin}{0}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\ymax}{1}
\begin{groupplot}[
  group style={
    group name=my plots,
    group size= 2 by 4,
    vertical sep=1.5cm
  },
  width=7cm,
  hide axis,
  enlargelimits=false,
  axis equal image,
]
  \nextgroupplot
    \addplot graphics [xmin=\xmin,xmax=\xmax,ymin=\ymin,ymax=\ymax]
          {example-image-a};
    \coordinate (top) at (rel axis cs:0,1);% coordinate at top of the first plot
  \nextgroupplot
    \addplot graphics [xmin=\xmin,xmax=\xmax,ymin=\ymin,ymax=\ymax]
          {example-image-a};
  \nextgroupplot
    \addplot graphics [xmin=\xmin,xmax=\xmax,ymin=\ymin,ymax=\ymax]
          {example-image-a};
  \nextgroupplot
    \addplot graphics [xmin=\xmin,xmax=\xmax,ymin=\ymin,ymax=\ymax]
          {example-image-a};
    \coordinate (bot) at (rel axis cs:1,0);% coordinate at bottom of the last plot
\end{groupplot}
% Labels
\node[below = 0.5cm of my plots c1r1.south] {(a) Timestep 25};
\node[below = 0.5cm of my plots c2r1.south] {(b) Timestep 35};
\node[below = 0.5cm of my plots c1r2.south] {(c) Timestep 45};
\node[below = 0.5cm of my plots c2r2.south] {(d) Timestep 55};
% Node position middle right groupplot
\path (top-|current bounding box.east)--
                    coordinate(legendposright)
                    (bot-|current bounding box.east);
% Node position middle above groupplot
\path (top|-current bounding box.north)--
                    coordinate(legendposabove)
                    (bot|-current bounding box.north);
% Node markers
%\node [circle,fill=black,minimum size=10pt] at (legendposright){};
%\node [circle,fill=black,minimum size=10pt] at (legendposabove){};
%Colorbar above
\begin{axis}[%
  hide axis,
  scale only axis,
  height=.01\linewidth,
  width=0.975\linewidth,
  at={(legendposabove.south)},
  yshift=1.25cm,
  anchor=south,
  point meta min=0.0,
  point meta max=2.0,
  colormap/bluered,                     % Colormap preset
  colorbar horizontal,                  % Active colorbar
  colorbar sampled,                     % Steps in colorbar
  colorbar style={
    separate axis lines,
    samples=256,                        % Number of steps
    xticklabel pos=upper
  },
  %every colorbar/.append style={
  %  width=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/parent axis width}%+
  %             %\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/group/vertical sep}
  %}
]
  \addplot [draw=none] coordinates {(0,0)};
\end{axis}
%Colorbar right
\begin{axis}[%
  hide axis,
  scale only axis,
  %height=0.975\linewidth,
  %width=0.01\linewidth,
  at={(legendposright.east)},
  anchor=east,
  xshift=0.25cm,
  point meta min=0.0,
  point meta max=2.0,
  colormap/bluered,                     % Colormap preset
  colorbar right,                  % Active colorbar
  colorbar sampled,                     % Steps in colorbar
  colorbar style={
    separate axis lines,
    samples=256,                        % Number of steps
  },
  every colorbar/.append style={
    height=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/parent axis height}%+
               %\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/group/vertical sep}
  }
]
  \addplot [draw=none] coordinates {(0,0)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Any improvements ideas?

Comment: just noticed: the right colorbar position breaks for `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}`